# Lightning ODATA connect How to create a Test coverage case

Tags: unit-test, odata

I have tried to create a test coverage method against a database Query which goes after an external object. The external datasource is a Lightning ODATA 2.0 connector. I setup the `MockHTTPcallout` but, it does not appear that the call is working. No errors, but no data is returned. Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

```
@isTest static void testGetSubmittedCSPQuotes() 
{
    String body = '{"QuoteNumber":"0030015397","QuoteType":"02","CustomerNumber":"0806253084","StatusCode":"AC","StartDate":"/Date(1452988800000)/","EndDate":"/Date(1455580800000)/","SubmitDate":"/Date(1452988800000)/","ReqDueDate":"/Date(1453075200000)/","LineCount":1,"QuoteValue":"0.00","SendEquoteToGcom":"N","EmailAddress":"806253084test@testing.com","SellerUserId": "CSPT1"}';
    SingleRequestMock fakeResponse = new SingleRequestMock(200, 'SUCCESS',body,null);
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeResponse);

    testUser1.FederationIdentifier='CSPT1';

    System.runAs(testUser1)
    {
      Test.startTest();
      List<Quotes__x> myQuotes1 = CSPQuoteCoreController.getSubmittedCSPQuotes(testUser1);
      Test.stopTest();  
    }

    system.assertEquals(1,myQuotes1.size());
}
```

Comment: can you share your test class code.

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test class for a controller that has logic to query the external object records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97225/test-class-for-a-controller-that-has-logic-to-query-the-external-object-records)